# How to extract the table of this page

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Well, in the following code I try to extract what is the table that is shown on the screen to be able to select the rows that have a status other than accepted, I attach the code that I am trying to use but the error that appears:

```
thead = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('thead')
columns = [th.text for th in thead.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')]

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

tbody = soup.find('table')
data = []
for td in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    row = [i.text for i in td.find_all('td')]

    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df.to_excel("files/prueba.xlsx")

driver.quit()
print("Realizado con exito")
```

The error is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty1Cn.png)

and the table that I want to extract the information to select is the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIuHZ.png)

If someone suggests another solution to go through the states of the oc and then select the boxes, the suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The error clearly states the problem: `columns` has 13 values but `data` only has 3 actual columns. You need to debug your code to figure out why this discrepancy happens.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the screenshot is:

```
ValueError: 13 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

[image]

This basically means you tried to create a dataframe where the number of columns does not equal (match) the row width (data).

You can read the line as:

> ValueError: I (the Python interpreter) found X number of columns to create from
> the column data width; however, looking at the width of the row data
> you gave me, you should have given me Y columns.  I cannot work out which is correct so I quit.

For a simple example let's first create a simple dataframe with equal columns and row data:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = list('abc') # = ['a', 'b', 'c']

data = [list('123')] # = [['1', '2', '3']]

# we're not saving this frame so we're not assigning it
print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns))

# >>    a  b  c
# >> 0  1  2  3
```

The above works because `a b c` is the same length as `1 2 3` (i.e., 3).

However, if we change the columns to be larger (without changing the row data) like this...

```
# create 13 columns (a-m)
columns = list('abcdefghijklm') # = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

data = [list('123')] # = [['1', '2', '3']]

print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns))

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AssertionError: 13 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
ValueError: 13 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

...it does not work and shows a whole bunch of errors.

When scraping (or whenever creating a dataframe), if you see that error check how many columns you are passing.